# Default database for SQL Server login

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

With [sp_defaultdb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181738%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can change the default database for a SQL Server login. And how do I show the current one (I mean the current default db for a specific login) programmaticaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT LOGINPROPERTY ( 'username' , 'DefaultDatabase' )
```

Or

```
SELECT name, default_database_name FROM SYS.server_principals
```

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL Server 2005 you can use the integrated function [DB_NAME (MSDN)](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189753.aspx):

```
SELECT DB_NAME();
```

Comment: I see, that my question was not precise enough. I wanted to know the current default db that is defined for a login. Rikalous' answer is what I was looking for. Sorry about that.